# Why does + operator overloading return type is class type not integer?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In this article the author chose the return type to be class type http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/*emphasized text* ,Can we just change the return type to return int, because i wanted to do the following , i tried this and it just worked fine , why did the author made the return type class ??

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Cents // defining new class
{
    private:
    int m_Cents;
    int m_Cents2;
    public:
    Cents(int Cents=0, int Cents2=0) // default constructor
    { 
        m_Cents=Cents;
        m_Cents2=Cents2;
}
Cents(const Cents &c1) {m_Cents = c1.m_Cents;}
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Cents &c1); //Overloading << operator
friend int operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2); //Overloading + operator
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Cents &c1)
{
out << "(" << c1.m_Cents << " , " << c1.m_Cents2 << ")" << endl;
return out; 
}
int operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2)
{
return ((c1.m_Cents + c2.m_Cents) + (c1.m_Cents2 + c2.m_Cents2 ));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Cents cCents(5, 6);
Cents bCents;
bCents = cCents;
cout << bCents << endl;
Cents gCents(cCents + bCents, 3);
cout << gCents << endl;
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you overload operators like `+` it should return the same type as the arguments!

Comment: Ok but what about this line : Cents gCents(cCents + bCents, 3); 
how can i pass two values to the constructor

Comment: If you added apples, would you return oranges ? So why do you want to return int when you add Cents ?

Comment: because i wanted this line Cents gCents(cCents + bCents, 3); so i can pass the sum of adding two cents and using it with another number to pass it to the constructor

Comment: Okay, C++ really doesn't make sense to you, and until you read this book a little more thoroughly every other thing is going to look completely nonsensical and you really shouldn't be posting every thing that looks nonsensical to SO.  I have to downvote that on this reason (i.e. no research effort).

Comment: @Amjad_bakir There wouldn't be need to do it like that if you'd have followed the tutorial exactly. `gCents = cCents + bCents` would work.

Comment: @iccthedral and what about the other value in the constructor (i want to pass two values)

Comment: Your constructor uses the class name `Cents` as a parameter name, e.g. `int Cents`. Don't do this.

Comment: @Derek thank you i didn't notice that

Comment: @iccthedral Ok sorry i will delete this but i really would like to know how to pass the sum of adding two classes to my constructor with another number (because my constructor just takes two integers) i can't pass a class type to it

Comment: Thanks everyone now i knew what i wanted to know , this was the answer that helped me : "Well, there's nothing to prevent you making a constructor that takes references to a Cents object as well (in addition to the constructor you already have). That would facilitate keeping everything in terms of Cents and give you type consistency"
i didn't know that i can make a constructor that takes a class object , sorry i'm still learning and thanks very much

Answer (score 10):

Apart from many other things, one thing to remember is that the result of the addition taking place between two objects of the same type is always of that very specific type. So it might work for you but logically it is incorrect.
Secondly, you are unable to perform nested `+` statements with not returning the class type.
For example if you want to do this.

```
Obj1 + Obj2 + Obj3 ;
```

You would get a compile time error.
The reason is that the overloaded function for `+` operator should return the result by value of the same class type. The operators written below could also be written for the function call as follows.

```
Obj1 + Obj2 ;
```

is equivalent to...

```
Obj1.operator+(Obj2) ;
```

For the nested addition operation, you do this way.

```
Obj1 + Obj2 + Obj3 ;
```

which is equivalent to....

```
(Obj1.operator+(Obj2)).operator+(Obj3) ;
|---------------------|
```

Here, this part...

```
(Obj1.operator+(Obj2))
```

becomes another temporary class object on which the next method gets called with `Obj3` as a parameter. So if you do not return class object from `+` function, this part would be an `int` instead of an object. The `+` function would not get called on that int or any other non-class data type. So it would give you an error.

In a nutshell, it is advisable to always return an object by Value, from overloaded `+` function.

Comment: Thank this was very helpful , i asked about that because my constructor is : Cents(int Cents=0, int Cents2=0) // default constructor
    { 
        m_Cents=Cents;
        m_Cents2=Cents2;
}
so i have to pass two integers (the sum of adding two classes and another number ) so that's why i changed the return type

Comment: Yes. You might change the return type if you are not up to something serious. But such situation could always be avoided by some optimization.

Comment: now i know the answer , i didn't think that i can make a new constructor that takes a class and an integer

Answer (score 2):

In general, the semantics of addition are that when you add two objects of a given type, you expect the resultant object to have the same type.

There's no reason you *can't* do what you want to do, but it is an example of nonstandard addition semantics.

Comment: my constructor is like the following : 
Cents(int Cents=0, int Cents2=0) // default constructor
    { 
        m_Cents=Cents;
        m_Cents2=Cents2;
}
so i wanted to pass two integers (the sum of the classes and another number) so i needed to change the return type to do so

Comment: Well, there's nothing to prevent you making a constructor that takes references to a Cents object as well (in addition to the constructor you already have).  That would facilitate keeping everything in terms of Cents and give you type consistency.

Comment: Thank u very much i thought this can't be happen , and sorry maybe i'm asking stupid questions but i'm still learning