# How can I implement operator overloading?

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a problem with my program. I want to create a two dimensional container and I don't know how to implement the operator overloading. Here is my code:

```
    template<class T, int N, int M>//az osztály sablonjai
    class my_matrix:public matrix_base<T,N,M>{
    public:
    my_matrix();

    ~my_matrix();

    T& operator=(my_matrix &rhs);

    T& operator()(int rhs,int lhs);

    T& operator+(my_matrix<T,N,M> &rhs);

    T& operator-(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs);

    T& operator*(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs);

    T& operator/(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs);

    private:
    T arr[N][M];//alap kétdimenziós tömb
    };

    my_matrix<T,N,M>::my_matrix<T,N,M>(){
    T arr[N][M];
    };

    my_matrix<T,N,M>::~my_matrix<T,N,M>(){
    delete[] arr;
    };

    T& operator=(my_matrix rhs){
    return this;
    };

    T& operator()(int rhs,int lhs){
    return arr[rhs][lhs];
    };

    T& my_matrix::operator+(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs){
    return this+lhs;
    };

    T& my_matrix::operator-(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs){
    return this-lhs;
    };

    T& my_matrix::operator*(my_matrix<T,N,M> rhs){
    return this*lhs;
    };

    T& my_matrix::operator/(my_matrix<T,N,M> &rhs){
    return this/lhs;
    };
```

I want to get this:
my_matrix m;
my_matrix m2;
...
m=m+m2;

matrix_base is an unknown abstract class(this is a task).
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code for + operator?
Maybe this can guide you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625075/why-does-operator-overloading-return-type-is-class-type-not-integer/12625114#12625114

Comment: What's the question? You don't know how to call the corresponding base function? Why is everything returning a `T &`?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you search the C++ FAQ and StackOverflow before posting.

For example, the C++ FAQ has a large section on Matrix classes and operator overloading.  Check this link out:  [C++ FAQ - Matrix overloaded operators](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/matrix-subscript-op.html)

### Edit 1: Added Effective C++

Another recommendation is to get Scott Meyer's Effective C++ books:
[Scott Meyer's Books on Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Scott-Meyers/e/B004BBEYYW)
Don't forget Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++:
[Herb Sutter's books on Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=Herb%20Sutter%20C%2b%2b)

Scott Meyer's books have sections on overloading operators, especially `+, -, +=` and `-=`.